# How to migrate Bitbucket to a DMZ server

Tags: migration, bitbucket, offline, dmz

I'm facing a migration of Bitbucket (version 6.0.0) to another Bitbucket instance (also version 6.0.0) which is inside a DMZ, so I just CANNOT connect both.

I have up, running & configured several repos inside each Bitbucket and now I want to migrate one single project (repo) from one Bitbucket instace to another, but, as stated above: I just cannot connect in any way from original server to final server.

Is there any possibility to export the repo to an USB and then import on the new one (and preserv all commits and traceability)?

Thanks and warm regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be as below.

Clone the repo(with --mirror option) from Bitbucket instance and copy this folder or connect your client machine to the network from where you have access to DMZ.

Here are the detail steps.

Migrating Source Code from one Bitbucket instance to another BB instance which is in DMZ.

1. Create a temporary directory.
2. Use git clone --mirror to pull down the code and branches from First BB instance.
3. Change the origin path of git remote set-url origin  to set the location. 
   (cmd : git remote set-url origin: ssh://git@dmz.companyname.com:7999/prjname/reponame.git)
4. Use git push --mirror to send branches to BB2_DMZ_Location server.
5. Use git push --tags to send tags to DMZ BB server.
   6 Delete temporary directory.
   The source code will be migrated from one BB instance to DMZ BB instance.

let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @rgh ! Thanks for your answer. That could be a possibilty ... the only point is that DMZ only allows to connect some devices, so I have to use one laptop for the origin Bitbucket, and another laptop for DMZ-destination Bitbucket. I cannot even have two laptops connected at the same network. Is there any possibility to run those commands against local-original-laptop repo, transfer it to USB device, then transfer it to destination-local-laptop and then to DMZ-destination Bitbucket server? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes, once you clone the repo. Copy complete repo folder to usb device and transfer it to where you want. Ensure folder permission are correct. Create an empty repo in  the dmz Bitbucket server. change the remote as mentioned above in the transferred repo folder and push all changes to new remote.

Comment: Hi @rgh ! I've marked the answer as valid but I forgot to comment. It worked like a charm. Thanks dude!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you. Thanks for your comment so that if anyone looking for this kind of requirement can get support and save time